# Using wildcard in must_not is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Hi I am new to elasticsearch, i am having issues using wildcard with must_not clause. I tried to put it in both query and filter context.

Example to text I am trying to exclude is "Error reported by EQRMS for GetSwaps(..) : 67890", works with match_phrase but not with wildcard and I have to use wildcard as the number in the end of the text changes

```
"must_not": [
    {
    "wildcard": {
      "message": "Error reported by EQRMS for GetSwaps*"          
    }
   ]
```

I tried using message.keyword as mentioned in other thread but that isn't working as well. Anyone can help?

Comment: Try this : `"Error\ reported\ by\ EQRMS\ for\ GetSwaps*"`

Comment: I am getting json_parse_exception,
"reason" : "Unrecognized character escape ' ' (code32)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBuffStreamInput@26167b2f; line : 8 , column : 33]

Comment: Ok. What is the field type of message?

Comment: This is I see in mappings,
```
"message_field": {
            "match": "message",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "index": true,
              "omit_norms": true,
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
```

"message": {
          "type": "text",
          "norms": false
        },